# php mysql / link not producing results

Tags: php, mysql

the link within the string is producing the results page just fine. However, no content is being displayed. Here is the string:

```
echo  '<td><a href="/results2.php?nameID= ' .$row['ID'].' ">' . substr($row['DESCR'], 0, 40) . '</a></td>';
```

What could I do in order to get the content to display on the results page? thank You

Comment: $row('ID') (or anything at all), won't have a value unless you have fetched it.  Did you do that?

Comment: correct, its been fetched within the "results.php" page.

Comment: `var_dump($row);` what's the result ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have space issue in the link,

```
 Change 
    echo  '<td><a href="/results2.php?nameID= ' .$row['ID'].' ">' . substr($row['DESCR'], 0, 40) . '</a></td>';
    To
    echo  '<td><a href="/results2.php?nameID=' .$row['ID'].'">' . substr($row['DESCR'], 0, 40) . '</a></td>';
```

Comment: Can you please select it as accepted answer and vote it up?

Answer (score 0):

I've added the new code, and unfortunately now, its not echoing out the string itself

echo  '' . substr($row[\'DESCR\'], 0, 40) . '';

is producing a blank page.